# checking common letters in a certain index in a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

So i have this predicate `letras_comuns(Lst,Common_ltrs)` in which Lst is a list of words like `[[a,n,o],[a,c,o],[a,t,o]]` and Commons_ltrs is the result of the common letters in all of those words at a certain index.

Example:

```
Lst_Pals = [[a,t,o], [a, c, o], [a,n,o], [a,l,o]], letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns).
Lst_Pals = [[a,t,o], [a, c, o], [a,n,o], [a,l,o]],
Letras_comuns = [(1, a),(3, o)].
```

So what this `[(1, a), (3, o)].` means is that all of the words have an `a` at the first index and that all of the words have an `o` at the 3rd index

Well to this i did this auxiliar predicate `letras_comuns_aux(Lst,Letra_comum,Index).` in which Lst is the same as before, Letra_comum is the common letter in all of the words at a given index, like `[(1, a)]` and index the specific index.

Example:

```
?- letras_comuns_aux([[a,t,o], [a, c, o], [a,n,o], [a,l,o]],Letra_comum,1).
Letra_comum = [(1, a)].

?- letras_comuns_aux([[a,t,o], [a, c, o], [a,n,o], [a,l,o]],Letra_comum,3).
Letra_comum = [(3, o)].
```

So basically this is giving the result i want at given index and this predicate is working fine, having said this what i tried to do is to do this verification for all indexes in Lst.

The problem is that for some reason this is giving an infinite cicle and i dont understand why.

Program:

```
letras_comuns_aux([],AC,_,_,AC) :- !.
letras_comuns_aux([P|R],Letra_comum,Index,El,_) :-
         nth1(Index,P,Ind_P),
         Ind_P == El,!,
         NAC = [(Index,El)],
         letras_comuns_aux(R,Letra_comum,Index,El,NAC).
letras_comuns_aux(_,Letra_comum,Index,El,_) :-
         NAC = [],!,
         letras_comuns_aux([],Letra_comum,Index,El,NAC).

letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns) :-
   length(Lst_Pals,C),
   NC is C + 1,
   letras_comuns(Lst_Pals,Letras_comuns,[],NC,1).

letras_comuns(_, AC,AC,Comp,Comp).
letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns,AC,Comp,Cont) :-
   letras_comuns_aux(Lst_Pals,Letra_comum,Cont),
   append(AC,Letra_comum,NAC),
   NCont is Cont +1,
   letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns,NAC,Comp,NCont).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly an endless loop:

```erlang
letras_comuns_aux(_,Letra_comum,Index,El,_) :-
         NAC = [],!,
         letras_comuns_aux([],Letra_comum,Index,El,NAC).
```

At every call, `NAC` is a fresh variable, that thereof will obviously will bind the empty list, and the recursive call then will receive such empty list as last parameter. What's the purpose of it ?

Now forgive my lazyness, but to understand your program is clearly more work than suggest a simpler idiomatic way:

```erlang
letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns) :-
    findall((L,I), foreach(member(X,Lst_Pals),nth1(I,X,L)), Letras_comuns).
```

This gives

```erlang
?- Lst_Pals = [[a,t,o], [a, c, o], [a,n,o], [a,l,o]],
|        letras_comuns(Lst_Pals, Letras_comuns).
Lst_Pals = [[a, t, o], [a, c, o], [a, n, o], [a, l, o]],
Letras_comuns = [(a, 1),  (o, 3)].
```

and is made possible by [foreach](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2)/2, that keeps variables bindings among successive calls of `Generator`.